# How to change all letters in a String to uppercase if the word Java appears in it?

Tags: java

```
String S = "Hallo, dit is een zin met alleen maar hoofdletters";
            if(S.length() > 10) {
                S = S.toUpperCase();
            }
            System.out.println(S);
```

This is what i get in Java as example, and below is the next question.

How to change all letters in a String to uppercase if the word Java appears in it ?

i can't figure this out.

PS. i am a beginner

Comment: Simple. Check if the word "Java" appears in the string, and if so, convert to upper case.

Comment: Read the documentation, you'll find everything you need: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: s = s.contains("Java") ? s.toUpperCase() : s;

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple and good exercise for a beginner. Start by reading about these simple api from the official javadoc.

[String.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) and [String.toUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()).

`.contains` return true/false boolean value for string you are checking, and `toUpperCase` is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

This is the elegant answer, I feel!

```
public void toUpperCaseIfJavaPresent(String input)
{
    if(input.contains("Java")){
        input = input.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("String contains the string Java : "+input);
    } else {
        System.out.println("String doesn't contain the string Java : "+input);
    }
}
```